# C Logical in If's And & Or with a numerical value

Tags: c, arduino

I am making a project for my school about digital locks and using an accelerometer. But the buzzer won't buzz with my code. I think I have some issues in logical operations in if's.

```
void loop() {
  recordAccelRegisters();
  if((gForceX || gForceY || gForceZ) > 1) {
    tone(2, 2000);
    delay(1000);
    noTone(2);
  }
  Serial.print(gForceX);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(gForceY);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(gForceZ);
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);
```

Comment: The expression `(gForceX || gForceY || gForceZ) > 1` is really equal to `((gForceX != 0) or (gForceY != 0) or (gForceZ != 0)) > 1`.

Comment: ..so what Some programmer dude mans is that must write it as `if(gForceX>1 || gForceY>1 || gForceZ > 1)`, if what you mean to check is "if any > 1"

Answer (score 3):

`((gForceX || gForceY || gForceZ) > 1)` is always false, because `(gForceX || gForceY || gForceZ)` return a boolean, and when you transform that boolean to an int you get 1 or 0, whose are never greater than 1

May be you wanted to write `if ((gForceX > 1) || (gForceY > 1) || (gForceZ > 1))` ?